# Ruby Comparing Time objects considers date. How to avoid that?

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

I have a model with a Time attribute

```
create_table "opened_intervals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time "start"
    t.time "end"
```

An example of a value would be:

```
>>  oi.start
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 06:26:00 UTC +00:00
```

(I am living in Germany)

If I use the current time, I get following value:

```
current_time = Time.now
>>  current_time
=> 2019-02-14 18:36:12 +0100
```

If I compare the class of both objects, I have

```
>>  current_time.class
=> Time
>>  oi.start.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

In order to make both instances same class, I change the Time class with the .zone method

```
>>  Time.zone.now
=> Thu, 14 Feb 2019 17:38:48 UTC +00:00
>>  Time.zone.now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Now both instances have same Class.

If I compare them, I get wrong results because of the date:

```
>>  oi.start
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 06:26:00 UTC +00:00
>>  current_time
=> Thu, 14 Feb 2019 17:40:13 UTC +00:00
>>  current_time < oi.end
=> false
```

I thought about creating a new Time with the hours, minutes and seconds, but then I have the same problem, Ruby always appends a Date.

Of course I could extract the hour, the minutes, the time, create an integer and compare them, but it feels too much.

- How can I deal with this issue the Ruby way?
- The Time object is always a time with a date? Is there no other way to achieve a Time just with the time?
- What would be the best approach for this problem?

I solved it this way:

```
def to_integer(time)
  hours = time.hour < 10 ? "0#{time.hour}" : time.hour
  minutes = time.min < 10 ? "0#{time.min}" : time.min
  seconds = time.sec < 10 ? "0#{time.sec}" : time.sec
  "#{hours}#{minutes}#{seconds}"
end
```

It feels too much (I could refactor it, but still too much)

```
to_integer(current_time) < to_integer(oi.end)
```

Comment: Check il seconds since midnight can help: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight

Comment: I don't quite get, what you are asking. Btw. you have first printed out `oi.start` only to later compare `current_time < oi.end`. And using `Time.current` will yield a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` right away. And comparing that with another instance of that class will work. But I probably just don't get the question.

Comment: i want to compare two times, but the date is in the mix, so i get wrong results. plus, why ruby stores a date, if i just want the time

Comment: According to a maybe outdated chart, a `time` column type in a migration will result in a [datetime column on sqlite3](https://jdc.io/rails-migration-data-types-mysql-postgresql-sqlite). PostgreSql and MySql turn it into a time column. As for comparison, I'd second @iGian's proposal: `Time.current.seconds_since_midnight <  oi.end.seconds_since_midnight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modulus the days off to get the remaining time value.

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = t2 = Time.at(Time.now.to_i - (5*24*3600))  # later time in day but previous date
tod1 = t.to_i % (24*3600)
=> 69734
tod2 = t2.to_i % (24*3600)
=> 69912
```

we can clearly see that t2 is a later time of day or clock time if you will and the modulus operation is very clear if you know anything about the unix epoch.